# FFmpeg: Documented method of changing frame rate not working

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

According to the FFmpeg documentation over [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video), I can change frame rate of a video using:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v copy -vsync drop -r 59.94 output.mkv
```

but all I am getting is an `av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument` error on my machine. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the log:

```
ffmpeg -i noaudio.mp4 -c:v copy -vsync drop -r 160 lapse.mp4

ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'noaudio.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:12:31.45, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 59950 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 59948 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
File 'lapse.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mp4, to 'lapse.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 59948 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 10240 tbn, 160 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 0x7fec5400e000] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A
video:794kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Here is a good answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/370692/how-to-change-the-framerate-of-a-video-without-reencoding

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the frame-rate without re-encoding the video file, so -c:v copy won´t work. Try to use -c:v libx264 -b:v  -r 59.94 and any other option you may need.

Comment: It is mentioned in the official documentation. This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If you want to duplicate the frame-rate, you have to process the video. That is a fact, not a question of making sense. If you use -c:v copy, you are not processing, ergo, not duplicating the frame rate. It is like trying to fry an egg with a cold pan and no oil.

Comment: Why do you think the frame rate is a property of a video? It's actually just part of "some meta tags" that tell a player at what framerate a video should be played. In other words, the frame rate can be thought of as an extrinsic property of a video rather than an intrinsic one. So it is easily manipulatable. And I have already done it without re-encoding the entire video.

Comment: I think so because the frame rate is a property of the video. If you manipulate the metadata, you will probably end up with a playback, for example, twice or half as fast. There is a simple way to prove that. Convert the video to YUV, and play it at different framerates. You will see that it is part of the video.

Comment: Don't tell me what you think, tell me what you know. Check out this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/370692/how-to-change-the-framerate-of-a-video-without-reencoding . Also, do you remember the good old days where frame rates could be manipulated by the speed of the projector reel? Ring any bells?

Comment: And, if you change the frame rate without reencoding, the playback will be faster/slower, and the duration of the movie will be shorter/longer than the original one.

And, regarding the link you shared, if you read more than only the first answer, you can see that the second comment is saying exactly the same as I do: "Changing framerate in the header of the video(container) has no effect on the videostream (or audiostream) itself. Reencoding is the only option."

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to achieve! i.e. speeding up my video by increasing the framerate. So yes, no reencoding was required. Now stop persisting.